# How to exclude tables from sp_msforeachtable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-msforeachtable

I know that `sp_msforeachtable` allows to perform queries on all tables.

I have 100 tables and I want to perform the same query on 97 tables.

I'm using this query: `EXEC sp_MSForEachTable "DELETE FROM ?"`

Is it possible to exclude certain tables?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') NOT IN (
                                                    ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T1]''),0),
                                                    ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T2]''),0)
                                                   )
                        DELETE FROM ?'
```

Answer (score 12):

Simplest syntax I came across to include or exclude schemas and tables:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'print ''?''', 
@whereand='and Schema_Id=Schema_id(''Value'') and o.Name like ''%Value%'''
```

Answer (score 6):

sp_MSforeachtable is undocumented procedure, but according by that example: http://avinashkt.blogspot.ru/2008/05/useful-operations-with-spmsforeachtable.html you could provide additional second parameter @whereand to limit list of tables.

---

The query that this gets appended to is the following.

```
SELECT   '[' + REPLACE(schema_name(syso.schema_id), N']', N']]') + ']' 
       + '.' 
       + '[' + REPLACE(object_name(o.id), N']', N']]') + ']'
FROM   dbo.sysobjects o
       JOIN sys.all_objects syso
         ON o.id = syso.object_id
WHERE  OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N'IsUserTable') = 1
       AND o.category & ltrim(str(CONVERT(INT, 0x0002))) = 0
```

So example syntax would be

```
   EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = N'PRINT ''?'' ', 
                          @whereand = 'AND o.id NOT IN (
                                                     ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T1]''),0), 
                                                     ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T2]''),0)  
                                                       )'
```