# How to delete data in all tables from a database except except few tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-msforeachtable

I have 50+ tables in my database and I want to delete all the data in 48 tables.

I tried using

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?  '

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER ALL'

EXEC sp_MSFOREACHTABLE 'SELECT * FROM ?'

GO
```

but it deletes all the data in all the tables.

Can some one suggest me what changes I need to make to delete data from all tables except TABLE1, TABLE2 etc in the query:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?  '
```

I am using SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852979/how-to-exclude-tables-from-sp-msforeachtable

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IF ''?'' NOT IN (''TABLE1'',''TABLE2'')` before your `DELETE FROM [?]`
By the way, I suggest using `TRUNCATE TABLE [?]` instead of `DELETE FROM [?]`