# To Rename Multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to rename multiple tables with same postfix like dbo.Denali_YLM_RedemptionStaging to dbo.Denali_YLM_RedemptionStaging_round3.
I want to add round3 at the end of 12 tables. Please suggest

Comment: the 12 tables are all tables into Database ? or just selected tables ?

Comment: There is a DB named jRewardToysRUs. There are many tables under this DB. I just want to rename 12 tables with same postfix as _round3 at the end.

Comment: so what is the issue for using `SP_RENAME` ?

Comment: Please suggest if there is a way to rename multiple tables in one query ?

Comment: What is the effort for running `SP_RENAME` for each table, especially these tables are selected and just 12 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dynamic SQL if you want to rename tables at once. For 12 just copy and pasting would be faster. This query adds `_round3` to all tables that ends with `RedemptionStaging`

```
declare @cmdNum int
declare @i int = 1
declare @cmd varchar(1000)

declare @t table(
    cmd varchar(1000)
    , rn int
)

insert into @t
select
    'exec sp_rename ''' + table_name + ''', ''' + table_name + '_round3'''
    , row_number() over (order by (select 1))
from
    information_schema.tables
where
    table_schema = 'dbo'
    and table_name like '%RedemptionStaging'


select @cmdNum = count(*) from @t

while @i <= @cmdNum
begin
    select @cmd = cmd from @t where rn = @i
    exec (@cmd)
    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I want to add _Round3 at the end of the below 12 tables. They all are from same DB.                                                                     
dbo SuperSaver_SingleUseCoupon
dbo SuperSaverDetail
dbo EpsilonDataSync
dbo CardAccrualOld
dbo SVS603
dbo DupeTranLog
dbo ImportHarteHanks
FileIO HH_Denali_Registry
dbo x
dbo stagingHarteHanks
EE GCUpdateData_01312017
dbo HHCardAccount
dbo zzz

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_msforeachtable. See here for more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mosharaf/2013/10/23/select-everything-from-every-table-in-every-database/

Comment: this approach will rename all tables, OP ask for specific tables.

Comment: You can limit the tables it uses. A great answer for this was provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852979/how-to-exclude-tables-from-sp-msforeachtable

Comment: SELECT 'exec sp_rename ''' + name + ''', ''Round3_' + name + ''''
FROM sysObjects
WHERE type = 'U' and name IN 
('SuperSaver_SingleUseCoupon','SuperSaverDetail','EpsilonDataSync','CardAccrualOld','SVS603','DupeTranLog',
'ImportHarteHanks','HH_Denali_Registry','x','stagingHarteHanks','GCUpdateData_01312017','HHCardAccount','zzz')                               This way can I do?